# Is there a program like NetStumbler for Ubuntu (to display the channels of local wifi networks)?

Tags: wireless, networking, indicator

NetStumbler is a program that show the local wifi networks and the channel they use. This is useful if one needs to choose a somewhat free channel for one's wifi connection. But this is in Windows.

What about an Ubuntu alternative?

---

**Update after answer** on using Kismet+Kismon: That is not at all like NetStumbler: I have to manually edit a configuration file.

From the links provided I understand that i have to install Kismet, and run `sudo lshw -C network` to get the needed data that I have to enter into a configuration file that is accessible by `sudo gedit /etc/kismet/kismet.conf`.

Running `sudo lshw -C network`, I get:

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5751M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 11
       serial: 00:14:c2:dd:01:c9
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.128 firmware=5751m-v3.29a latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:c8000000-c800ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:02:04.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 05
       serial: 00:15:00:3b:d1:20
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipw2200 driverversion=1.2.2kmprq firmware=ABG:9.0.5.27 (Dec 12 2007) ip=192.168.0.10 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=24 mingnt=3 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:21 memory:c8400000-c8400fff
```

So confusing. 9 pages of forum for that? can i get simple instructions?

Also, I worry for something like:

```
~$ kismet
Launching kismet_server: //usr/bin/kismet_server
Suid priv-dropping disabled.  This may not be secure.
Done
```

What does this mean, not secure?

Also, [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1067390&p=6750143#post6750143)  it says: "when quitting kismet, it leaves your wireless card stuck in monitor mode. To revert back to Managed mode (client mode), the commands would be similar to the following:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Managed
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

What does this mean? Do I have to run those (in fact not those lines, but other, similar but different info ---) each time (after) I use Kismet?

In the configuration file I have edited only 2 lines:

13 `suiduser=cipricus`

and

27 `source=ipw2200,eth1,intel`

But this is what happens:

```
~$ kismet
Launching kismet_server: //usr/bin/kismet_server
Suid priv-dropping disabled.  This may not be secure.
Done.
```

And:

```
~$ kismon

(kismon:7877): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(kismon:7877): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(kismon:7877): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(kismon:7877): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(kismon:7877): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Client: start 127.0.0.1:2501
Client: Open connection to 127.0.0.1:2501 failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused
kismet_server must be running to get live data
Client: stop
```

Comment: Try out either http://askubuntu.com/a/55748/67335 or http://askubuntu.com/a/56626/67335.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find which WiFi frequencies are being used the most near by?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55740/how-to-find-which-wifi-frequencies-are-being-used-the-most-near-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible duplicate of [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/55740/47206), but under there, the real answer to **this** question - a program like NetStumbler from Windows - is [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/457712/47206):

[**LinSSID**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linssid/?source=typ_redirect)